# Area of diagonal-folded regular polygon

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry

I have a piece of paper whose shape is a regular `n`-gon with side length `1`. Then I fold it through some of its diagonals. What is the area of the shape formed by the (former) edges of the regular polygon?

### Illustration

Suppose `n = 8`, i.e. an octagon-shaped paper. Let's name the vertices from A to H (left picture). Then I fold the paper along the two diagonals BE and FH (right picture). Mathematically, folding BE means to reflect the vertices C and D with respect to the line BE to obtain C' and D'. Your task is to calculate the area of the shaded octagon on the right picture.

[image]

### Input

The number of sides `n` and a list representation of the folds `l`. Each element of `l` represents either a fold or an intact side of the polygon. If it is a fold, its value is the number of sides moved by the fold (e.g. 3 for the `BE` fold above, 2 for `FH`). Otherwise, the value is 1 (e.g. for the sides `AB`, `EF`, `AH`).

For the example above, the input will be `8, [1, 3, 1, 2, 1]` if we count from the vertex A, counter-clockwise. If we count clockwise from E instead, the input will be `8, [3, 1, 1, 2, 1]`; the expected answer is the same.

Note that `sum(l) == n`. Also, `l == [1] * n` (1 repeated n times) case is just the regular polygon untouched, which is a valid input.

**The resulting polygon is guaranteed to be simple** (it does not intersect or touch itself). For `n=3` or `n=4`, this means that the only valid input is the polygon folded zero times. For `n=6`, `l=[1, 2, 2, 1]` or `l=[1, 2, 1, 2]` is invalid because the two folds will cause two folded vertices to meet at the center of the hexagon.

### Output

The area of the `n`-sided polygon created by the given folds. The result must be within `1e-6` absolute/relative error from the expected result.

### Scoring & winning criterion

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. Shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
n l => answer
---------------
4 [1, 1, 1, 1]    => 1.000000
5 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] => 1.720477
5 [2, 1, 1, 1]    => 0.769421
6 [1, 2, 1, 1, 1] => 1.732051
7 [1, 2, 1, 2, 1] => 2.070249
8 [1, 3, 1, 2, 1] => 1.707107
```

The picture below shows the first five test cases.

[image]

[A reference implementation in Python](https://tio.run/##XZHBaoQwEIbvPsXAHjYR17aubouwpz5G6SHoRAOaSMxSltJnt5OktlqIMn4zf/6Zcbq73ujzshzgVQzNbRAOwfUIwqIAI0NssaOEhckM985o@FCuh1m1CAPqjuKnLLIGrRNKB/EM0gwttom0ZoRRUFqNk7EuhQOJdQaNmTOYVAZ5nictSpDMX0rQK2deJ@DtnYArlcFDsJwJWgKPeRWIZqGEE@5/sRMbPClskFI9JQryXqeIPHTXoHZofS3lgptPpdGQJDcdZ1m1VCmNBQU0a@jVt/qjPl2BrXoFp9BRSi3HxzdchEwaZ@OcosJbW6XdbgEZHD/r/CK/jjm50QaZN@A87KqLpbzeCmlCVvqbaf6/jXHOF8nKDN7oP9Ep3nmy/fYnoGqHtrTYo0ss/Eeft7RY6Uuk5y3tWOlfFV@@AQ).

Answer (score 8):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>37</s> 36 bytes

```
Tr[Csc[i=Pi/#2]^2Sin[2i#]-Cot@i#]/4&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P6Qo2rk4OTrTNiBTX9koNs4oODMv2ihTOVbXOb/EAUjrm6j9DyjKzCuJVta184tOc3BQjo1V03eo5qquNtQBw1odk1odBBckYAoWMELlGurABcyQBIxAAuZQAWOYgEUtV@1/AA)

Takes input in the order `l, n`.

Uses the same approach as in the reference and many other implementations.

Mathematica's trigonometric and arithmetic functions will automatically vectorize, and `Tr` returns the sum of the elements of a one-dimensional list.

\$\csc\$ and \$\cot\$ are relatively uncommon; \$\csc x=\frac1{\sin x}\$, and \$\cot x=\frac1{\tan x}\$.

Comment: Nice solution.  Do you mind adding an explanation?

Comment: @Jonah it turned out to be the same as the reference implementation, but I'll add a little in.

Answer (score 8):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>79 .. 66</s> 65 bytes

```ruby
->n,f{(f*2+[w=-1]*n).sum{|z|(w**z*=b=2r/n).imag/(1-w**b).real}/4}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bctNCsMgEAXgfU4xy8RqRJv@bOxFxIVCLYUmBEsITfTs1taNoR3eYngfz03mFa2I5DJgu9YW8Z2cBWEKDU37nPrVL76eEVqQMII7mtp7r2@0ZiS1pmndVT8C7UKUIKHDIBmGFK4gn8IVbOQTVchhI18shP/dHPOG/25OpfBSzln2pVSq7fW4eo2NhxGsTI8K8Q0)

Loosely based on the reference implementation:
[image: Original image]

- The area of the original polygon (ABCDEFGH) is `a`
- If we cut instead of folding, we get a new convex polygon (ABEFH), we call the area of this polygon `b`
- The difference between `a` and `b` is the area of the polygons we cut away (BCDE and FGH), let's call it `c`
- The area of the folded polygon is `b-c` or `a-2c` (we have to remove BCDE and FGH twice from the original polygon). This equals to `2b-a`
- Both `a` and `b` can be represented as the sum of triangles (formed by 2 radiuses of the enclosing circle and one side of the polygon). Yes, we have a formula for calculating `a`, but if we define an intermediate function `g` it's easier to use it for both `a` and `b`
- The area of a triangle is r*r*sin(2lπ/n) where l is the number of vertices in a fold and n is the total number of vertices, and r is the radius (which is 1/sin(π/n))
- `a` is the sum of n triangles with l=1
- since `g(-x)=-g(x)`, we don't need to split the sum in 2 parts, we can sum over a larger array (that is twice f plus [-1] repeated n times), the intermediate function can become a block.
- sin(x)^2 becomes (1-cos(2x))/2
- sin(2π/x) and cos(2π/x) are imaginary and real part of the xth root of -1.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>87 83 82 79</s>  72 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Shaggy*
*Saved 7 bytes thanks to @GB's insight*

Takes input as `(n)(list)`. Derived from the reference implementation.

```javascript
with(Math)f=n=>a=>a.map(v=>n+=sin(2*v*T)/sin(T)**2,n/=-tan(T=PI/n))&&n/4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bctPa8JAEAXwez7FnGQmrgld/xXK5mahB8GDt7CHISYmxc6KWWK/fYzmsq0O7zCPH@@bO26LS3P2M3GHsu@vja9xy76myojJeEjyw2fsTCZT0zaCOu7iPaX3d09xrJWkZuZ5aGb3lQrRZCLpov/II4AcFgryNwVDtIXxrPon99hAln/kgYHol5vVuNHPm3UoOpT3UeahRDZKKnfZcFEj5qKALYHJoHDSulOZnNwRKxRCpsS7z@a3POCKiPob)

Given the number of sides \$n\$ and the folding values \$F_1\$ to \$F_m\$, this computes:

$$A=\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{n}{\tan(\theta)}+\sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{\sin(2\theta F_i)}{\sin(\theta)^2}\right)$$

with \$\theta=\dfrac{\pi}{n}\$

Comment: [80 bytes](https://tio.run/##bcs/a8MwEAXw3Z/ipnCnKhZVk7RQ5K2FDoHsRsPh2LWb9BRi4fbbO068qH@ON9zjx/vggfvq3J3iUsK@HsevLra45dhS48QVPCX/5BMOrhAny8EclL3rO0GrBhXJXN9ISlktxh1c5Km63ZsRosVCzGp8LjOAElYaynsNU6yH@bz@Jdf4RNY/5IaJ2H83m3lj/24eU7GpPM3ykErms7wJ5xeuWsRSNLAncAVUQfpwrPNjeMcGhZApj@G1@673uCGi8QI)

Comment: You can take the 2Fi/t out of the sum. t is a constant and the sum of Fi is n.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>123</s> <s>114</s> <s>112</s> 103 bytes

```java
a->n->{double t=Math.PI/n,T=Math.sin(t);n/=-Math.tan(t);for(int v:a)n+=Math.sin(2*v*t)/T/T;return n/4;}
```

Port of the Python reference implementation.
-11 bytes by porting [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195777/52210).
-9 bytes thanks to [*@G.B*'s insight](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/195775/area-of-diagonal-folded-regular-polygon/195792?noredirect=1#comment465934_195777).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hZJLb8IwDIDv/AqrpwbaVBTYJjqQJk1IOyBNgxvikNEUwkpaNW4nhPjtLKQwXt1oDo3tz3b8WLKCucvwazeLmVIwZEJuagAKGYoZLLWV5ihiGuVyhiKRdHC4PAuJk6nzL/Ka5J8xd6D89/sQQW/H3L50@5vQ6AB7Q4YL@v7mSWdc3pWQNpJAej3XyMiMHCWZrXNC0WVENk6oXy/qSLyxNw4yjnkmQXrtYLsLarqOVCfRdRzKKRIRwkqXaI8wE3I@mQIj@3IBRmuFfEWTHGmqTRhL2xqJkKuu1bDAohlPOUO7QxrWIInDK7W/139wlcfYBYuY1ADIFdotByT/BtOtTdPRZ6vtv@b2jfke4F@YOxX@VxEuEL8CeLiMUYU83iL@FfJ0ibTOkW3ttFNmCMbjsAJq32andIRo39y/Z2LY8843m@5RaREacznHhU1I47SWL1nG1opiUs7cLjOcx2g13Xv4WWTztIovoixN4/XRoRTM08ihB9vdDw)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <sup><s>41</s></sup> 35 bytes

```apl
{4÷⍨(+/(1○2×⍵×t)÷2*⍨1○t)-⍺÷3○t←○÷⍺}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG9qQMCjtgnm/6tNDm9/1LtCQ1tfw/DR9G6jw9Mf9W49PL1E8/B2Iy2gBEiwRFP3Ue@uw9uNQWygLiAF0rSr9n8aiNfb96ir@VHvmke9Ww6tN37UNhFoenCQM5AM8fAM/m@ikKZgCIFcpgg2lGcEZZuBZWA8czgPiLkswDxjCA8A)

Uses [Arnauld's expression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195777/80214) for calculating the area.

-6 bytes from ovs. (removing inner dfn)

### Explanation

```apl
{4÷⍨(+/(1○2×⍵×t)÷2*⍨1○t)-⍺÷3○t←○÷⍺} ⍺ → n, ⍵ → l
                             t←○÷⍺  assign t to Π/n (○÷n = (○1)÷n)
    (                  )            apply the following to each element of l:
       (1○2×⍵×t)                       sin(2×element×t)
                ÷                      divided by
                 2*⍨1○t                sin(t)²
    (+/                             sum the results
                        -           minus:
                         ⍺          n
                          ÷         divided by
                           3○t      tan(t)
 4÷⍨                                divide that whole expression by 4
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>36</s> <s>31</s> <s>30</s> <s>25</s> 23 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
·žqI/©*®šÅ½ćn/OI®Å¼/-4/
```

Folds-list as first input, sides-integer as second input.

Port of [my Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195788/52210).
-5 bytes by porting [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195777/52210).
-1 byte thanks to *@Grimy*.
-5 bytes thanks to [*@G.B*'s insight](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/195775/area-of-diagonal-folded-regular-polygon/195792?noredirect=1#comment465934_195777).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0Paj@wo99Q@t1Dq07ujCw62H9h5pz9P39zy0Dsjeo69rov//f7ShjrGOoY6RjmEslwUA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/h5ulir6SQmJeioGTv6RIKZD9qmwRk/z@0/ei@wgj9Qyu1Dq07uvBw66G9R9rz9P0jDq0Dsvfo65ro/9f5H22oA4SxXMZcEBaIbQJhG8FZUHFTrmgjJDZQBYxnBuMZgXjmIJ4xjGcBAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
·               # Double each value in the (implicit) input-list
 žq             # Push PI
   I/           # Divide it by the input-integer
     ©          # Store this PI/input in variable `®` (without popping)
      *         # Multiply this to each doubled value in the list
       ®š       # Prepend `®` (PI/input) to this list
         Å½     # Take the sine of each value in the list
           ć    # Pop and push remainder-list and first item separated to the stack
            n   # Square this first item: sin(PI/input)²
             /  # Divide each value in the list by this
              O # And then sum all values together 
  ®Å¼           # Get the tangent of `®`: tan(PI/input)
 I   /          # And divide the input-integer by this
      -         # Subtract it from the sum
       4/       # And divide it by 4
                # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: [-1 by sharing the `·`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/h5ulir6SQmJeioGTv6RIKZD9qmwRk/z@0/dzWo/sKI/QPrdQ63Hpo76F1IDJPvxLM2HNopb5urX/EoXX62ib6/3X@RxvqAGEslzEXhAVim0DYRnAWVNyUK9oIiQ1UAeOZwXhGIJ45iGcM41kAAA)

Comment: As noticed by GB, my formula was overcomplicated. You should be able to save a couple of bytes in your ports as well.

Comment: @Arnauld Thanks for letting me know. -9 in my Java port and -5 in 05AB1E :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>81</s> 79 bytes

```python
lambda n,f,a=-1:sum([(a**(2/n*r)).imag/(1-a**(2/n)).real for r in f*2+[a]*n])/4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bctBDoIwEAXQvaeYZVuLhIJoSDhJ7WKMVpvQQiouPH2l1gSIzvzVf/nDa7z3rgy6PYUO7fmC4Ljm2GZF83haIgkyRkTumKd0ZyzeclJk325q/BU70L0HD8aBZmIrUTGnaF6FWJtYy@krDrLgMEUoSKc4rCBGzbBfwcdmEP8WdVqIn8VhCWIBxwTlElSzARi8cSPRhBlKwxs)

A Python port of my Ruby solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>60</s> 57 bytes

-2 and -1 thanks to Nick Kennedy and CriminallyVulgar!

```r
function(n,l,t=pi/n)(sum(sin(2*t*l)/sin(t)^2)-n/tan(t))/4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcrNCoAgEATge0/RcVcMyX4P9SpBBIJgW9T6/EbSj8xl5mOOYPKhCMbTwnYjIOkkj7tVhHD6FU5LoAULh@qujJPGghTPd0dVBwO1XKCUMYiZgebfiehkt/GRSveJfqSPUr0SLg)

Comment: Save 2 bytes: https://tio.run/##TcpLCoAwDATQvadwmWilWOtnoVcRRCgUahSN569Y/JTZzDxm9ybtC29OmtmuBCSc4GGzkhAKkjwRMObHucBhCVTGmUN5V8ZRIUrtDWgxQylCEBMD9b8jUdFuwiOW9hP1SBekesVf

Comment: Cheeky extra byte on top of @NickKennedy's [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcrNCoAgEATge0/RcVcMyX4P9SpBBIJgW9T6/EbSj8xl5mOOYPKhCMbTwnYjIOkkj7tVhHD6FU5LoAULh@qujJPGghTPd0dVBwO1XKCUMYiZgebfiehkt/GRSveJfqSPUr0SLg "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 108 bytes

```
procedure g(s,f)
r:=.5/sin(t:=&pi/s)
p:=s*(c:=.25/tan(t))
p-:=(c*(i:=!f)-r*r*sin(2*i*t)/2)*2&\z
return p
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc/BDoIwDAbg@55iXsi6gItT1CzZk6gHAoPs4Fi6ERNfHkfwAIm49LT/a5vaunfj6LGvTTOgoR0LeQsEld6XIljHotKZtyIA8UoHzuqUyFLEKkWQPgulWc2ZVXrXQoEc@dQlueURhAQus/uboIkDOuqJcc1i2bNKFAhN74U2GtaxU05vh5x@6wHrtFylG0D@A@d5gtwElyWQP8B1BscVmO76AA)

An [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon) port of the Python reference implementation.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 23 bytes

```
×ḤÆS÷ÆS²¥_ÆTİ×ɗS
ØP÷ç÷4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w9Ic7lhxuCz68HUgc2nRoafzhtpAjGw5PPzk9mOvwjACg@PLD203@H530cOcM60cNcxR07RQeNcy1Prxcn@tw@6OmNZH//0dzKShEK5joKEQb6igAkVGsAgTE6qDJgFAskowpigxYEknGCKseM4geI0w95sgyRsgyFhAZY2QZrlgA)

A full program that takes the number of sides as its first argument and the list of folds as its right. Returns/prints the area of the folded polygon.

Loosely based on the [formula in @Arnauld’s answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195777/42248)